# how to capture road traffic data for a specific period and place

Tags: traffic

I would like to capture road traffic data for a specific location and in a specific period and then I require to do some analysis on data. I try to check how I can do that. I found that I am able to use some public API for obtaining traffic information but I feel there could be other way as well. I require this data for a Big Data project.

Please suggest me how I should store data as well, I mean what is the best practice for store a big range of data of traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is very general! As I understand and based on my experience,
I suggest you something:

1- First and most efficient is that you can analysis your data online then extract your statistics and keep your results.
Easy for research here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detecting-cars-in-a-video-of-traffic.html

2- You can tag your data and keep only the sequences that you need, at least ignore a big unnecessary data automatically.

3- If you need to keep the video sequences for any reasons, then I suggest to use video compressors and decrease your videos not only by compressors also in terms of size.
http://video-compressor.en.softonic.com/